# How to get many checkboxes in one single row using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to show all the 7 days of week in a form.
They currently are getting shown like so:

[image: Messed up alignment]

With this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Day(s) of Week</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" value="1">
      Su
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" value="2">
      Mo
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" value="3">
      Tu
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-3" value="4">
      We
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" value="5">
      Th
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-5">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-5" value="6">
      Fr
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-6">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-6" value="7">
      Sa
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make all of them show in a single line / row ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arrange them inside a table

Comment: It is already inline. Checked in Bootstrap.http://www.bootply.com/BoCPhlIYTm What is the width of the container holding it?

Comment: Make your column wider. You are probably watching this on too narrow screen. You could set it to `col-md-8`.

Answer (score 3):

put your code within `container` and `row` such as below code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        //Your code
    </div>
 </div>
```

your code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">   
<label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="checkboxes">Day(s) of  Week</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" value="1">
  Su
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" value="2">
  Mo
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" value="3">
  Tu
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-3" value="4">
  We
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" value="5">
  Th
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-5" value="6">
  Fr
</label>
<label class="col-md-1 checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-6" value="7">
  Sa
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```